# Modern status of private Docker registries/repos

Tags: docker

So it's great that the public Docker registry exists; that way, if I want an out-of-the-box image for a MySQL server, or an nginx proxy, I can just use one pulled from the public registry as-is.

But obviously the public repo is no place to store my closed-source, application images. So I asked the Google Gods for the available options surrounding setting up private Docker registries, similar to how I publish all my binaries to a local [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/artifactory/) server. And I find the lack of private registry support most disturbing.

The main articles I found were:

- https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/
- https://github.com/docker/docker-registry
- https://blog.docker.com/2013/07/how-to-use-your-own-registry/

However they are old and I know there have been recent major changes in Docker (`libcontainer` -> `runc`) that likely obsolesces them. So I ask: are there modern, Artifactory-like tools out there for hosting private Docker registries? If not, is there an easy recipe for rolling your own?

**Bonus points** if someone can explain to me the difference between: Docker indexes, registries and repositories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the terminology:

- A repository is a collection of images e.g the `redis` repository contains images for various versions of `redis`. A particular image is selected by specifying a tag e.g `redis:3.0`. If no tag is specified when pulling an image, it defaults to the `latest` tag.
- A registry is a collection of repositories, the primary example being the Docker Hub.
- "index" I think is old terminology that you can forget about.

(I expect bonus points now ;) )

As @Abdullah Jibaly points out, you can have private repositories on the Docker Hub.

You can also run your own registry, instructions are on the [Docker distribution GitHub project](https://docs.docker.com/registry/configuration/). This is in no way obsoleted by runc (nor does it really have anything to do with runc).

There are also other hosted registry solutions such as http://quay.io.

Answer (score 0):

https://hub.docker.com supports [private images](https://registry.hub.docker.com/plans/) as well (similar to the github model), I'd start with that first.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same task to look into recently. If you don't want to use the already mentioned private cloud offerings, there is (in the meanwhile) support for private (on premise) docker registries with:

- JFrog Artifactory
- Sonatype Nexus 3
- GitLab
- OpenShift